# Applescript: Batch save files in Preview without save dialog

Tags: applescript, batch-processing

thanks in advance for your help.

New to Applescript.
Trying to open in Preview all files in folder and save them.
The problem is that saving pops up a dialog half the time, which requires me to sit there hitting enter.

Code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set fl to files of folder POSIX file "/Users/myname/Desktop/myfolder/" as alias list
end tell

repeat with f in fl
    tell application "Preview"
        activate  
        open f

        # Trying to save before the window has appeared will fail.
        # Note: - This assumes that NO window was initially open.
        #  - The code should be made more robust to eventually time out.

        repeat until (count of windows) > 0
            delay 0.3
        end repeat
        save front document
        close front document
    end tell
end repeat
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Looking your script, it seems you just open and save your files. isn't it quicker to just move or duplicate your files to required folder ? or is it that you want to change file format (default image=jpg) ?

Comment: the files are pdfs forms. I am trying to collect the response data from the forms, but at some point some of the pdfs versions changed and I get an error when trying to add many of the files to the response form. This issue came up before, apparently, and the solution was to save the files in preview, as it automatically converts them to the same version of pdf (something I didn't know before). This has worked in small scale tests. Trying to make an applescript to open and save all files in preview to get them to all be same pdf version.

Comment: I made test of your script with several PDF files (different version from 2007 to 2016, from websites or home made). no issue. when your script stops, asking you to hit enter key, it is probably because the pdf as something very special. once we know what makes that file version special, we could hit enter in the script, but we must know the file characteristic to let script knows. can you see differences between a file which works and one which requires enter ? in info window, is it special version ? special coding ?

Comment: Hmmm, all the files with the save dialog show the .pdf extension when viewed in the folder. I tried unchecking all the "show extension" checkboxes in "Get Info", but the same files still have a save dialog with the extensions unchecked. Also, it is trying to save the files in Documents...maybe a standard "Save As" operation?

Comment: The ones that trigger the dialog have "Encoding Software: Mac OS X 10.7.3 Quartz PDFContext" and are "Version: 1.6" vs "Encoding Software: Mac OS X 10.9.5 Quartz PDFContext" and "Version: 1.3" on the ones that don't.

Answer (score 0):

I made several PDF files and download from different sites and I get sample of version 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.7, ..but no 1.6 ! For all of them no issue.

Anyway, because I have not been able to reproduce what you have, I took different approach.

1) I have added at top of the script, a list of encoding/version list which may required special treatment (like hit return key). You can of course amend these 2 lists to manage other cases you may have.

2) I changed your script to allow the script to get encoding and version values of the pdf. This is done by using spotlight data base via shell command 'mdls'. I use it 2 times to get version and encoding characteristics. The shell command returns characters before and after the value we want to get, so I use text x thru Y to extract the encoding and the version itself.

3) if PDF version/encoding are in the list predefined which requires special treatment, then I set OKReturn to true.

4) Just after the save instruction, the script now test if OKReturn is true. then I ask the script to hit return key for you. you may have to adjust this part, for instance, it could be not only 1 return, but 2 or something else. this is something I have not been able to test, because all my pdf are working. please keep in mind that because I simulate return key, you should not use the keyboard during the script run.

based on my test, I don't think the encoding is the blocking criteria. I think the version 1.6 is.Here is the script. It includes comment to make you able to adjust it:

set CodingReturn to {"Mac OS X 10.7.3 Quartz PDFContext"}
   set VersionReturn to {"1.6"}

```
set myFolder to choose folder
tell application "Finder"
set fl to files of myFolder as alias list
end tell

repeat with f in fl
set FVersion to do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemVersion " & quoted form of POSIX path of f
set FEncoding to do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemEncodingApplications " & quoted form of POSIX path of f
if (length of FVersion) > 21 then set FVersion to text 19 thru -2 of FVersion -- extract only version number
if (length of FEncoding) > 42 then set FEncoding to text 38 thru -4 of FEncoding -- extract only the coding

set OKReturn to ((FVersion is in VersionReturn) and (FEncoding is in CodingReturn)) -- special treatment true/false

tell application "Preview"
    activate
    open f

    repeat until (count of windows) > 0
        delay 0.3
    end repeat
    save front document

    if OKReturn then -- we need special key to be pressed
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
    end if

    close front document
end tell
end repeat
```

I would be very interested to get your feedback about this version.

Comment: I think the problem with the above solution is that without a path to save to, Preview opens a "Save As" dialog and the save command doesn't get completed until you manually click the save button. Trying to get automator to hit the enter key won't work because that step can't run until the "save" operation resolves.

Answer (score 0):

To save without the "save as" dialog popping up, add "in f". Here "f" was the filename. You could also put in a different path.

```
save front document in f
```